# List view inside scroll view design

Tags: android-layout

I have a UI design which should contain a text data and this can be dynamic so i need a scroll view after the TextView is over i need a list view, Now this list view onItemClick of a cell should expand and contract to show details, Any sample project or code from where i can achieve this UI design, Please help me with this one.

Answer (score 2):

It is strongly not recommended to have Nested Views that scroll.

What you can do is have a TextView followed by the ListView. You can use expandable listView for your expansion requirement. All the examples are present in APIDemos shipped with Android SDK.

Try some of the stuff and get back for more help here.